Factoring of cyclotomic polynomial modulo prime power, Chinese remainder theorem and automorphisms
I'm having trouble with the implementation of ring Chinese Remainder Theorem with cyclotomic polynomials.
To be precise, given cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi_m(x)$ and some prime power $p^r$ such that $p \nmid m$, it is known that $\Phi_m(x) = \prod_{i=1}^k F_i(x) \pmod {p^r}$ for some degree-$d$ polynomials $F_1, \dots, F_k$ where $d$ is the multiplicative order of $p$ modulo $m$, and $d \cdot k = \phi(m)$. (This can be easily obtained by applying the Berlekamp algorithm and Hensel lifting.)
Then, we can apply the Chinese remainder theorem to reconstruct some ring element $r \in \mathbb{Z}_{p^r}[x]/\Phi_m(x)$ such that $r \equiv r_i \pmod{F_i}$ for some finite ring elements $r_i~(1 \le i \le k)$.
Here are my questions:

Is there any efficient algorithm to perform Chinese remainder theorem rather than tower structure? As it is an cyclotomic ring, I think there should be an FFT-like method rather than a naive Chinese remainder tree.
Applying automorphisms $X \mapsto X^\alpha$ to the ring element $r$ will result in a permutation of the remainders $r_i$'s, if $\alpha \neq p, p^2, \dots, p^{d-1}$. Is there any efficient algorithm to determine the permutation instantiated by $\alpha$, without automorphism-and-then-remainder, given the polynomial factors $F_1, \dots, F_k$?

Is anyone familiar with these kind of algorithms? I could not find any helpful informations or papers online. Thank you in advance.

Edit : The automorphism $X \mapsto X^\alpha$ will act as a permutation as long as the remainders $r_i$ are constant polynomials. Still, some $\alpha$ will act as a permutation..

Chinese remainder theorem is always ring.

Part 1
This is a partial answer that applies in cases where $d$ is "small".
I also assume for now that $r = 1$, but everything works out just as well for larger $r$ when you replace the finite field $\mathbb{F}_{p^d}$ with a Galois ring.
In this case, your idea on FFT-like methods seems like a good start. In particular, when $d$ is small, the roots of unity live over the "small" finite field $\mathbb{F}_{p^d}$, and the FFT over $\mathbb{F}_{p^d}$ (sometimes also called number-theoretic transform, NTT) computes the map
$$ \mathbb{F}_{p^d}^m \to \mathbb{F}_{p^d}^m, \quad (a_i) \mapsto \Bigl(\sum_i a_i \zeta^{ij}_m\Bigr)_j $$
This corresponds to the evaluation of a degree-$(m - 1)$ polynomial at all $m$-th roots of unity, or equivalently to the map
$$ \phi: \{ f \in \mathbb{F}_{p^d}[X] \ | \ \deg(f) < m \} \to \mathbb{F}_{p^d}^m, \quad f \mapsto (f \ \text{mod} \ (X - \zeta^i))_i$$
Note that the inverse map of this is already very close to what you want, and can be efficiently computed using the inverse FFT. Note also that if we identify the polynomials $f \in \mathbb{F}_{p^d}[X]$ of degree $<m$ with $\mathbb{F}_{p^d}[X]/(X^m - 1)$ and equip $\mathbb{F}_{p^d}^m$ with component-wise multiplication, this becomes a ring isomorphism.
The next step is now to study the restriction of this isomorphism $\phi$ to polynomial with coefficients in $\mathbb{F}_p$. For this, consider the action of the power-of-$p$ Frobenius automorphism $\pi$.
It turns out that on $\phi(\mathbb{F}_p[X]/(X^m - 1)) \subseteq \mathbb{F}_{p^d}^m$, $\pi$ acts as a permutation (more precisely, $\phi \circ \pi \circ \phi^{-1}$ does)
$$ \mathbb{F}_{p^d}^m \to \mathbb{F}_{p^d}^m, \quad (a_i) \mapsto (a_{pi \text{ mod } m})_i $$
This is quite an interesting statement. In particular, it is another way to show that $d$ is the multiplicative order of $p$ in the group $(\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})^*$, and furthermore, the restriction of $\phi$ to polynomials over $\mathbb{F}_p$ is
$$ \phi(\mathbb{F}_p[X]/(X^m - 1)) = \{ (a_i) \ | \ a_{pi \text{ mod } m} = a_i^p \text{ for all i} \} $$
Furthermore, we see that the factors $F_i$ must be $F_i = \prod_j (X - \zeta^{ip^j})$ where $i$ runs through any set of representatives of $(\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})^*/\langle p \rangle$.
This gives us now an explicit way of computing the inverse CRT.
Given $r_i \in \mathbb{F}_p[X]/(F_i)$ where $F_i = \prod_j (X - \zeta^{ip^j})$ (w.r.t. a fixed set of representatives of $(\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})^*/\langle p \rangle$), for each $k \in \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$, set
$$ \tilde{r}_k = r_i(\zeta^{ip^j}) \quad \text{where $k = ip^j \in (\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})^*$} $$
Finally, compute the $r := \phi^{-1}(\tilde{r})$ efficiently using the inverse NTT. If you want to get the result modulo $\Phi_m$ instead of $(X^m - 1)$, you can use $r \text{ mod } \Phi_m$ instead.
Some remarks

When implementing this, be careful about automorphisms. In particular, the field $\mathbb{F}_{p^d}$ has nontrivial automorphisms, and thus there is no unique way of identifying $\mathbb{F}_{p^d}$ with $\mathbb{F}_p[X]/(F_i)$, we even have $\mathbb{F}_p[X]/(F_i) \cong \mathbb{F}_p[X]/(F_j)$.
If $d$ is large, the math works out just the same, but the arithmetic in $\mathbb{F}_{p^d}$ will become more and more expensive, and at some point it might become slower than the generic approach based on the euclidean algorithm (although I haven't tested this).
I have encountered this problem when doing homomorphic encryption, since the plaintext space in some of those schemes is exactly $\mathbb{F}_p[X]/(\Phi_m)$. Unfortunately, all papers on the topic that describe the computational structure of this are quite hard to read, and don't go into the details. You might also want to have a look at my implementation of this, however it follows the HE literature in that it heavily exploits the tensor-decompositions $\mathbb{F}_p[X]/(\Phi_m) \cong \mathbb{F}_p[X]/(\Phi_{m_1}) \otimes \mathbb{F}_p[X]/(\Phi_{m_2})$ whenever $m = m_1m_2$ with $m_1$, $m_2$ coprime, and the code is likely to be extremely hard to understand if you are not familar with the setting.
Edit I have just seen that in my implementation, I actually use the naive approach based on Euclid's algorithm.

Part 2
It is not quite true that the automorphisms permute the remainders $r_i$. Instead, they permute the list that contains all remainders and their Galois conjugates (w.r.t. $\mathbb{F}_p[X]/(F_i)$).
Consider a variant of the $\phi$ considered before, namely
$$ \phi': \mathbb{F}_{p^d}[X]/\Phi_m \to \mathbb{F}_{p^d}^{(\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})^*}, \quad f \mapsto (f \mod (X - \zeta^i))_i $$
where the domain should be the vectors over $\mathbb{F}_{p^d}$ whose indices are elements of the group of units $(\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})^*$.
Then the automorphism $X \mapsto X^\alpha$ (note that it is only an automorphism if $\alpha \in (\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})^*$) acts as the permutation
$$ \mathbb{F}_{p^d}^{(\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})^*} \to \mathbb{F}_{p^d}^{(\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})^*}, \quad (a_i)_i \mapsto (a_{\alpha i})_i $$
Note that the remainders $r_i$ and their Galois conjugates in $\mathbb{F}_{p^d}$ correspond to the coefficients of the vector $\phi'(r)$, so they are indeed permuted by $X \mapsto X^\alpha$, and this permutation is given by the multiplication with $\alpha$ in the group $(\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})^*$.
To be somewhat more concrete, first note that exactly as above, we have
$$ \phi'(\mathbb{F}_p[X]/(\Phi_m)) = \{ (a_i) \ | \ a_{ip} = a_i^p \ \text{for all $i \in (\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})^*$} \} $$
where now the multiplication $i p$ happens in $(\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})^*$.
This means that if a polynomial $r \in \mathbb{F}_p[X]/(\Phi_m)$ has remainders $r_i$ modulo $F_i$ (where we set $F_i = \prod_j (X - \zeta^{i p^j})$ with $i$ running through a set of representatives of $(\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})^*$ as before), then $\phi'(r)$ can be given as
$$ \phi'(r)_j = r_i(\zeta^{ip^l}) \ \text{where $j = i p^l$} $$
In particular, applying the automorphism $\sigma: X \mapsto X^\alpha$ gives new value $r' = \sigma(r)$ where the $i$-th remainder $r'_i$ is $r_j(X^\alpha) \text{ mod } F_i$, with $jp^l = \alpha i$ (this equality here means we choose $j$ as the unique integer that appears as index of one $F_j$, and for this one, there then exists $p^l$ such that $jp^l = \alpha i$). In other words, the automorphism does not just permute the remainders $r_1, ..., r_k$, but also can transform each one by applying a Galois automorphism (which does not have to be the same for each one as well).
